# Convert Key Value Pair table data to XML Using SQL

Tags: xml, t-sql, pivot

I have a table in the following shape

```
RecordID      KeyText      ValueText
--------      -------      ---------
1             "A Key 1"    "Some text for A Key 1"
1             "A Key 2"    "Some text for A Key 2"
2             "A Key 1"    "Some text for A Key 1"
.....
```

Any given RecordID (which is a foreign key to a master record) can have one or more rows in this table.

I want to group these into a single record for each RecordID with an XML type field in the following format

```
RecordID: 1
<LegacyDataItem>
    <Field Key="A Key 1" Value="Some text for A Key 1" />
    <Field Key="A Key 2" Value="Some text for A Key 2" />
</LegacyDataItem>

RecordID:2
<LegacyDataItem>
    <Field Key="A Key 1" Value="Some text for A Key 1" />
</LegacyDataItem>

.....
```

How can I output the XML using SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(RecordID INT,KeyText VARCHAR(100),ValueText VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
 (1,'A Key 1','Some text for A Key 1')
,(1,'A Key 2','Some text for A Key 2')
,(2,'A Key 1','Some text for A Key 1');

SELECT RecordID 
      ,(
        SELECT m2.KeyText AS [@Key]
              ,m2.ValueText AS [@Value]
        FROM @mockupTable AS m2
        WHERE m2.RecordID=m.RecordID
        FOR XML PATH('Field'),ROOT('LegacyDataItem'),TYPE
       )
FROM @mockupTable AS m
GROUP BY RecordID;
```

The result:

```
RecordID    XML
1           <LegacyDataItem><Field Key="A Key 1" Value="Some text for A Key 1" /><Field Key="A Key 2" Value="Some text for A Key 2" /></LegacyDataItem>
2           <LegacyDataItem><Field Key="A Key 1" Value="Some text for A Key 1" /></LegacyDataItem>
```

The outer select will group by the `RecordID`, the subselect looks for the related records and returns them as XML